# Difference between 'Directory' and 'Python Package' in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, python-packaging

[image: Denter image description here]

1. When to use Directory over Python Package? PS: I understand that I can import from latter but not former. If so, why not create everything as a Python Package?
2. Also, does PyCharm mark a location as one or the other based on its name? What is the pattern behind this behavior? 
   For example, I created a Directory and named it 'lambda'. But when I renamed it to 'lambdas', pycharm automatically changed it to a Python Package (the briefcase with dot symbol). Python keyword?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> When to use Directory over Python Package?

You can use "Python Package" when you want to put some modules in there which should be importable. PyCharm will automatically create an `__init__.py` for the directory.

> Why not create everything as a Python Package?

Not every subdirectory in a project should necessarily be a package.  For example `docs` and `tests` are commonly just directories.

> Does PyCharm mark a location as one or the other based on its name?

PyCharm seems to mark the icon with a dot if the subdirectory name [is a valid identifier and not a keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), regardless of whether the subdirectory is a package or not. This is possibly because, in Python 3.3+, subdirs are also [implicit namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) (they are still importable even when there is no `__init__.py` file).

If you have a project associated with a Python 2.7 interpreter, you don't get the dot on the icon unless the `__init__.py` file is added, since implicit namespace packages are not a thing in Python 2.

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, in Python 3.3+, PyCharm marks a subdir with a dot anyways (as long as it is an 'identifier'). Does that mean that every subdir is importable in this case? if so, how do I unmark that like for tests and docs, like you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, it means every subdir is importable.  I don't know how to unmark it in PyCharm, probably you can't.

Comment: from services.StockAnalyzer import StockReport
either the services has __init__.py or not I can import in this way can you explain what kind of constraints would I have if I have init file or not I do not understand the difference